# How to change the displayed label for Wordpress default fields?

Tags: wordpress

Looking to change the displayed Label of the default (not a CPT) field "Title" to something like "Name" instead.

Note: Don't need to change the actual field name... just what is displayed to a user on the front end.

[I think it is simple, but unfortunately, the terms I've searched on are just too generic (eg, "Title" or "Label") that I get too many hits for everything but what I'm looking to do.]

I think something like this is the way to go? (Correct me if off-base here, or a better way to do this.)

```
'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Name' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Name' )
```

but how is this applied to an existing field? If it were a new filed, then register_post_type would created it and pass along the names.  But don't know if wise to try to re-register something already registered? (Would that cause problems? Or does it just gracefully accept any changes in the second?)

Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: An interesting question although I am not sure that is the right code to update if all you want to do is change how something appears on the frontend. Instead of changing label configuration for a post type, why not just output what you want in the frontend template? Please share some of the code where you are actually outputting frontend code where this is an issue.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I'm asking specifically about a way to globally change this in one place, as the theme itself is programmatically inserting the title in a few places (eg, there is a specialized search function that uses the default name as label for the form field). Not only would I have to find the code, and then insert a test for this specific field and insert a string instead of the name, but I would have to hunt and find every situation where this happens and address each independently.   So would be much easier/cleaner if I could make just one global change.